# Maven War: Filename of deployment descriptor

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

So I've added the maven-war-plugin to my pom.xml and added:

```
<configuration>
    <webXml>WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml</webXml>
</configuration>
```

Now when I package my app this descriptor gets renamed to web.xml which causes a failure when trying to deploy my application to my glassfish server, since the server thinks the web.xml is malformatted I guess. 
So how can I tell maven to leave the file name untouched?

Answer (score 0):

`<webXml>` configuration isn't mandatory for `maven-war-plugin`. So, If you don't explicitly mention the webXml, It won't rename the file. You will get the expected behaviour if you remove this webXml entry from your `pom.xml`

**Edit 1**

I don't think there is an option to skip webXml file renaming. You can try **[copy-resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)** task in `maven-resources plugin`. You can configure a resource file/directory mappings from Project dir to War archive.

```
    <plugins>
        <-- other plugin configurations.... -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                        ${basedir}/target/app/WEB-INF
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                          <resource>
                            <directory>WEB-INF</directory>
                            <includes>glassfish-web.xml</includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>{another directory from where all files are copied}
                            </directory>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                           <directory>
                           {another directory from where, all but test.properties are copied}
                           </directory>
                           <excludes>test.properties</excludes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  <plugins/>
```

Comment: If I remove the <webXml> entry in the configuration section of the war-plugin then it works ONLY IF I move the glassfish-web.xml to the following location: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml
What if my project structure deviates from this? I want to have my WEB-INF folder at the top level of my application. The <webXml> tag seems to be there for exactly this reason, so you can reference a deployment descriptor in a location other than the default one. So I'm still looking for a way to prevent maven from renaming.

Comment: I've updated the answer. 

**What if my project structure deviates from this?** 

I think it is the purpose of **copy-resources**